# Meteor/Stripe: Receiving XMLHttpRequest cannot load error when attempting to post data to server side route in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, stripe-payments

A few obvious items:

I'm using Meteor Router.
I've installed the Email package via Meteorite.

---

Here's what I'm attempting to do:

1. When a user signs up, I have Stripe setup to create a customer on their end (working).
2. When that customer is created, Stripe creates an event and via webhooks, shares the data for that event with me by sending post data to http://myapp.meteor.com/stripe.
3. When the post data is received, my application extracts the email address for the customer and triggers a Meteor method which sends an email to that address.

The problem I'm having is that on the first attempt (i.e. when the original event occurs), I receive a 503 error in Stripe. However, if I fire the request again from within Stripe, Meteor accepts it and sends the email just fine. Why would it work the second time (and subsequent times after that), but not the first. Here is my current code:

```
if(Meteor.isServer) {

  Meteor.startup(function () {
    process.env.MAIL_URL = /* OBSCURED */;
  });

  Meteor.methods({

    sendEmail: function(address, subject, text) {

      Email.send({
        to: address,
        from: "test@myapp.com", /* OBSCURED ADDRESS */
        subject: subject,
        text: text
      });

    }

  });

  Meteor.Router.add(

    '/stripe', 'POST', function() {  

      // Grab Post Data
      post = this.request.body;

      // Test Type of Post
               type = post.type
      customerEmail = post.data.object.email;        

      var email = [customerEmail, "Welcome to My App!", type];

      Meteor.apply("sendEmail", email);

      return [200, "Success"];

  });

}
```

What I have noticed is that when the Stripe request is sent, I see the following in my console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://ddp--0675-[myapp].meteor.com/sockjs/903/1szdgor_/xhr. Origin http://[myapp].meteor.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Could you show what you are using on the client as the error originates from the browser

Comment: @Akshat Nothing on the client. The '/stripe' route is what fires all of the functions. It only does so when Stripe posts data to that route. Otherwise nothing. Does that answer your question or are you looking for something else?

Comment: What I mean is the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` can only originate from the browser. The thing is in the code above you don't make an XHR request, nor is there any meteor code in your custom server route as its just "Success" (no html either). So the error might not be something that bothers your app

Comment: I know someone who already solved this. I'll try and get him to post an answer here (if he can't I'll post it myself when I get the details).